# Forcing Spring to return status 200 on HEAD requests

Tags: java, spring, controller, servlet-filters

I need to make a Filter that will catch all HEAD requests and will return status 200 on them.

As I undertand, I need to create a Filter that will catch every HEAD request, which is done, and do something to return 200 on every requests, which is a question.

I mean filter catches request and able to do something with it, but I need not a request, but a response that will be 200.  So what else can I do?

```
public class HttpHeadFilter implements Filter {
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    if (isHttpHead(httpServletRequest)) {
        chain.doFilter(new ForceHeadToOkStatusWrapper (httpServletRequest), response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

public void destroy() {
}

private boolean isHttpHead(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "HEAD".equals(request.getMethod());
}

private class ForceHeadToOkStatusWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public ForceGetRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }
    //somethig here
}
}
```

Comment: Why so complex? Why would you even need to call `doFilter`? Use do `response.setStatus(200)` and don't call `doFilter`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what looked for. We can send response without processing the request. :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've created an interceptor:

```
public class HttpHeadInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

      if (isHttpHead(request)) {
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  }

  private boolean isHttpHead(HttpServletRequest request) {
      return HttpMethod.HEAD.equals(request.getMethod());
  }

}
```

And added it to WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new HttpHeadInterceptor());
}
```

And it works smooth)